# How can I check if my python scripts are being run in a certain way (with a debugger of some sort)

Tags: python

How can I detect how the python script is run???

I have tried using visual studio but that didn't work

```py
if debugger: # If debugger is on
    print(data)
```

How would I use such 'debugger' and I don't want it to print to a log file.

Comment: at the top of code set `debugger = True` to run it. And after testing set  `debugger = False`

Comment: you don't need `()` in `if debugger:`. And `else: pass` is useless so you can remove it.

Comment: you can also use module [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to get arguments in command line - `python script.py --debug`

Comment: @furas yes, I can use what you said, however, is it possible to print to some third-party application, like visual studio debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pdb: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html.

```
if debugger:
    pdb.set_trace()
```

This will enter an interactive debugging session where you can see the value of ''data'' and everything else in the current scope. I'm not aware of any method you can use to send the output to a third-party debugger.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful!